# How to fix "Unable to find location of java.lang.Thread.setName() in debuggee JVM

Tags: java, swing

I have created a `JFrame` form for simple data capture, and it was running fine. Now when I run it in Ecplise, I get nothing and this warning comes up:

> Unable to find location of `java.lang.Thread.setName()` in debuggee, for type `java.lang.Thread`.

.My form never loads and there are no errors.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: 2019-06 (4.12.0)